# Doxigen "Called by" information from function documented in another config-file

Tags: doxygen, cross-reference

I want to keep the "called by" information for functions called from another package as the documented in the current configuration file. It is easily possible to exclude the complete files, directories etc from being documented in the current set but in this case I lose the information about the calls from the excuded parts of source to the functions being documented.
Is there a way to parse the group of files and to consider the information inside of these files but not to include the description of functions in this files into the current document?

Thank you in advance